# how to catch the jquery ajax function return value in another variable

Tags: javascript

I am looking to store a value which is return by the AJAX function, here is the my code, in the AJAX success it is showing well, but when am storing that data which is saying undefined.

The following `serviceNumber`, which I am storing the `enCrypt` return value

```
var serviceNumber = enCrypt(typeofServiceNumber);// when am catching the function data which is saying "undefined"
```

the following code is my ajax function

```
function enCrypt(id) {
if (id > 0) {
    $.ajax({
        url: $("baseUrl").html() + "JobProfiles/Encryption",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: { Id: id },
        success: function (encdata) {
                   return encdata; 
        },
        error: function (data) {
            $('#loading').hide();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Can you help me to know what is wrong in my code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [access to a variable "outside" of a callback function in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42666843/access-to-a-variable-outside-of-a-callback-function-in-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add the

```
 cache: false,
 async: false,
```

to you ajax function

```
function enCrypt(id) {
var encnum;
$.ajax({
    url: $("baseUrl").html() + "JobProfiles/EncodeIds",
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    async: false,
    dataType: "Json",
    data: { Ids: id },
    success: function (encdata) {
        encnum = encdata;
    },
    error: function (data) {
        $('#loading').hide();
    }

    });
    return encnum;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can't use return like this, because the function is async + it's a function in a function...so actually yeah you cant return there xD

Just do something like:

```
enCrypt(typeofServiceNumber);

//and in your ajax:
success: function (encdata) {
                   go_on(encdata);
        },

//and then
function go_on(serviceNumber)
{
    //here you can use it :D
}
```